# Possible counterexample to the strong three exponentials conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

There is something wrong possibly either with me or with Wikipedia.

Wikipedia's article on the [strong three exponentials conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture#Three_exponentials_conjecture)

defines $L^\ast$ as the set of all complex numbers of the form

$$\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i\log\alpha_i$$
where all the $\beta_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are algebraic and every branch of the logarithm is considered.

> The strong three exponentials conjecture meanwhile states that if $x_1, x_2$, and $y$ are non-zero complex numbers with $x_1/x_2$ and $y/x_2$ both being transcendental, then at least one of the three numbers $x_1 y, x_2 y, x_2/x_1$ is not in $L^\ast$.

This appears a counterexample:

$$ x_1 =\sqrt{2} ,x_2=\frac12 \sqrt{2}\log{2}, y=1$$

$x_1/x_2$ and $y/x_2$ contain $\log{2}$ and are transcendental.
The products are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1 y =& \sqrt{2} \\ 
x_2 y =& \frac12 \sqrt{2}\log{2}\\
x_2 / x_1 =& \frac12 \log{2} &
\end{aligned}
$$

and these are visibly in $L^\ast$.

> Is this a counterexample?
>
> Is there a more serious reference for the strong three exponentials conjecture?

Couldn't find it on the web and Wikipedia is not allways reliable source.

Comment: The only source cited in the three exponentials section of the WP article is http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~miw/articles/pdf/Hyderabad.pdf . Did you look at it?

Comment: @Emil thanks. I saw that, but 1.9 appears different from this and the paper doesn't mention strong three exponentials.

Comment: Also, the WP article claims the strong 3 exp. conj. follows from the strong 4 exp. conj. Can you produce a counterexample to the latter? If not, this would suggest that the article is in error.

Comment: Maybe there's supposed to be a condition, $\alpha_i\ne1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson There might be well missing condition, though your condition is not enough. $y$ can be any algebraic number in the example.

Comment: If $x_1$ and $y$ are both algebraic, then for $x_1y$ to be in $L^*$, you have to allow $\alpha_i=1$, or else allow $n=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK, I see now. Pasted the definition of L* from Wikipedia and don't think any algebraic number is excluded.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For positive $a,k$ one cancel all the logs via $\log{a^k}=k \log{a}$, so $\alpha_i \ne 1$ appears to not be a problem.

Comment: If you have access to Math Reviews, maybe the best idea is to look up "three exponentials" there.